# PHP CodeIgniter echo svg graph (SVGGraph)

Tags: html, codeigniter, graph, svg, inline

So i've just begun working with SVGGraph http://www.goat1000.com/svggraph.php.. I'm quite happy with it but it's not really playing nice inside my CodeIgniter app.

I have a function to create the graph.
At the end I can call either

$graph->Render('PieGraph')

OR

$graph->Fetch('PieGraph')

Ideally i'd like to be able to call the function to return the graph so I could just echo the graph wherever it is needed.

Currently, I can only do this with the header/content type set to "image/svg+xml" The problem with that is that I can't print out anything else in the document then.

Any ideas on how I can get SVG's to work inline with html so I can insert them just like I would a regular graphic.

Thanks.

P.S. I would usually post some code here but I don't have anything that is near correct. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested it but something like this should work for you,

```
class Test extends CI_Controller {

    // Here in this method you define svg graphics
    function get_svg()
    {
        header('Content-type: image/svg+xml');
         $graph = new SVGGraph(640, 480);
         $graph->colours = array('red','green','blue');
         $graph->Values(100, 200, 150);
         $graph->Links('/Tom/', '/Dick/', '/Harry/');
         $graph->Render('BarGraph');
    }

    // This is the index method
    function index()
    {
        $this->view('test');
    }
}

// In view page view/test.php

<body>
    <embed type="image/svg+xml" src="<?php echo site_url('test/get_svg') ?>"; height="300" width="500"/> 
</body>
```

Comment: Cheers, that was one solution I was sure would work but I was trying to avoid calling the function via a URL reguest..

How would I go about using the above method when there's a lot of graph data. Suggestions welcome..

Thanks.

Comment: humm... passing parameter to the method eg. get_svg($option) to get different svg output should make maintaining and implementing code easier.

Comment: another idea is you could use php funtion ob_start(); and ob_get_contents(); to store content of svg class to a variable and then pass it to view page,
bit complicated yes but it should work too.